# Consider the two parameter family of linear systems.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'_{1}(t)=ay_{1}(t)+by_{2}(t)$$
$$y'_{2}(t)=-by_{1}(t)+ay_{2}(t)$$

I know my determinant is $a^2+b^2$ and my trace is $2a$. To find my eigenvalues I think I look at $a\pm bi$.

In the $ab$ plane identify all the regions where this system possesses a saddle, a sink, a spiral sink.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that
$$
(y_1+iy_2)'=(a-ib)(y_1+iy_2)
$$
and
$$
(y_1-iy_2)'=(a+ib)(y_1-iy_2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your calculations, since the equation for eigenvalues, for a 2 by 2 matrix, in terms of its determinant and trace are given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807166/eigenvalues-in-terms-of-trace-and-determinant-for-matrices-larger-than-2-x-2) as

$$
\lambda = \frac12 \left(\text{tr} \pm \sqrt{\text{tr}^2-4\det}\right).
$$

In general it might be easier to solve it with

$$
\det\left(A - \lambda I\right)=0,
$$

where $A$ is a matrix, such that $\dot{\vec{y}}=A\vec{y}$, $I$ the identity matrix of the same size as $A$ and $\lambda$ the eigenvalues, which have to be solved for such that the equation is true.

Comment: Oh thanks! I figured out what I did wrong. I have that my eigenvalues values are a+_bi, does this mean that in my trace determinant graph, I got that spirals sink in the 2nd and 3rd quadrant and spiral sources in the 1st and 4th and center along the b'axis?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of solving this problem, along the lines of my answer here: [Trace Determinant Plane Differential Eqns](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54878/169085). Let's assume that we are allowed use the trace-determinant plane and the different behavioral regions of it.

Let us first put $A_{a,b}=\begin{pmatrix} a& b\\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$. Then like the OP states $\operatorname{tr}(A_{a,b})=2a$ and $\det{A_{a,b}}=a^2+b^2$. After the answer I referred to above, let us consider the coordinate change from the $ab$-plane to the $td$-plane

$$\Phi: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2,\,\, \begin{pmatrix} a\\b \end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 2a\\a^2+b^2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

As in my previous answer, this coordinate change is natural as $\Phi(a,b)=(\operatorname{tr}(A_{a,b}),\det(A_{a,b}))$.

Next we need to optimize $\Phi$ a bit. First note that $\Phi\begin{pmatrix}a\\-b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$, so that $\Phi$ is two-to-one except when $b=0$, in which case it is one-to-one. Next note that $\dfrac{(2a)^2}{4}=a^2\leq a^2+b^2$, so that the image of $\Phi$ is precisely

$$R=\left\{(t,d)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\left|\, \dfrac{t^2}{4}\leq d\right.\right\}.$$

Thus we have two inverses for $\Phi$, one with the upper half $ab$-plane as the image and another with the lower half $ab$-plane as the image:

\begin{align*}
\Phi^{-1}_+:&R \to \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{\geq0},\, \begin{pmatrix}t\\d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto  \begin{pmatrix}\frac{t}{2}\\\sqrt{d-\frac{t^2}{4}}\end{pmatrix}\\
\Phi^{-1}_-:&R \to \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{\leq0},\, \begin{pmatrix}t\\d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto  \begin{pmatrix}\frac{t}{2}\\-\sqrt{d-\frac{t^2}{4}}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Here is a humble caricature summarizing the situation (the trace-determinant plane is from Hirsch, Smale and Devaney's *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos* (3e, p.64)):

[image]

This exactly matches with the OP's conclusion in a comment.

---

Finally note that in the critical case $\dfrac{t^2}{4}=d$, we have $b=0$, so that $A_{a,b}=A_{\frac{t}{2},0}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{t}{2}&0\\0&\frac{t}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ is a diagonal matrix; hence accordingly we have either a star sink (if $t<0$), a star source (if $t>0$), or all equilibrium solutions (if $t=0$).